# Sql query to get not exist records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 4 tables
Table1
UserId(PK)----------   UserName
1------------------ ABC
2-------------------PQR

Table2
CustId(PK)---------CustName
1-----------------------Cust1
2-----------------------Cust2
3-----------------------Cust3

Table3
CustId(FK)----------UserId(FK)
1-----------------------1
2-----------------------2

Table4
OfficeId(PK)----------OfficeName--------CustId(Fk)
1------------------------Off1-------------------1
2------------------------Off2-------------------1
3------------------------Off3-------------------2

Tabl5
OfficeId(FK)----------UserId
1-------------------------1
3-------------------------2

The question is when User is associated to 3 Cust,but he is assigned offices belonging to only 2 of the Cust, then it should returns the unassigned officeId?
From above tables,
When I pass UserId=1 to my stored procedure
I want following output

OfficeId---------OfficeName
2-----------------Off2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not want to keep track of which tables are which, so I am using table names that make more sense (to me)...

using `not exists()`

```
select o.OfficeId, o.OfficeName
from users_customers uc
  inner join office o
    on uc.CustId = o.CustId
where uc.UserId = @UserId
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from users_office uo
    where uo.UserId = @UserId
      and uo.OfficeId = o.OfficeId
  )
```

using `except` (this will also remove duplicate results)

```
select o.OfficeId, o.OfficeName
from users_customers uc
  inner join office o
    on uc.CustId = o.CustId
where uc.UserId = @UserId

except

select o.OfficeId, o.OfficeName
from users_office uo
  inner join office o 
    on uo.OfficeId = o.OfficeId
where uo.UserId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT OfficeId, OfficeName
FROM Table4
WHERE OfficeId NOT IN (
    SELECT Table4.OfficeId
    FROM Table3
    INNER JOIN Table4
        ON Table3.CustId = Table4.CustId
    INNER JOIN Tabl5
        ON Tabl5.UserId = Tabl3.UserId
        AND Tabl5.OfficeId = Table4.OfficeId
);
```